# How do I create crontab job to launch Monero miner on server reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I am attempting to create a crontab job that will run every time my server (Ubuntu 16.04) reboots. I would like the command to run in a new screen. If I run the following command in command line it works every time. The command below starts my Monero miner.

```
screen minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45560 -u XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com -p x
```

Below is an image of my crontab job. I created it with root. When I reboot the server the the process I am expecting to be running in a new screen is not. No process is running and no other screen has been created.

[image]

Here is the crontab code if you don't want to view the image:

```
@reboot screen minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45560 -u XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com -p x
```

Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To monitor your process and enable auto-restart on server crash or process crash I would recommend using `systemd` instead. You first specify a daemon service with the correct configuration then enable the service with the `systemctl`.

1. Create a `systemd` service file:
   `sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/miner.service`
2. Edit the `systemd` service file (Replace ${} placeholders):

   [Unit] 
   Description=Monero Miner
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Type=forking
   User=${YOUR_USER}
   Groupt=${YOUR_GROUP}
   ExecStart = ${PATH_TO_MINER}/minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45560 -u XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com -p x
   WorkingDirectory=~
   Restart=on-failure

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target

*Remark: You might need to change `Type=forking` to `Type=simple` if your miner does not fork itself when starting.*

3. Make`systemd` aware of your service:
   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
4. Enable your new service:
   `sudo systemctl enable miner`